# How to make tk.Button() fill width of window while using .grid()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've made a program that makes a pie chart using `matplotlib.pyplot` and it has a GUI which I made using `tkinter`, and I'm having problems with buttons. They don't fit the width of the window! This is the first time I'm using `tkinter`, so I don't know how to do that.
[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id6eC.png)

Here's the snippet of my code which packs the buttons into the window:

```
append_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Add values to register",
    command=append
)
make_chart_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Make chart",
    command=make_chart
)
clear_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Clear all registered values",
    command=clear
)
exit_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Exit Pie Chart Creator",
    command=_exit_
)
append_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="E")
make_chart_btn.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="W")
clear_btn.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="E")
exit_btn.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="W")
```

Comment: Use `sticky="EW"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided doesn't work. Please strip the unused functions out to make it work.
Nevertheless, the :

```
sticky="WENS"
```

flag is what you are looking for probably.

`Sticky` flag defines how to expand the widget if the resulting cell is larger than the widget itself. In your case you want to fill the cell thus expand it in all directions.

Thus the resulting window might look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

append_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Add values to register",
)
make_chart_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Make chart",
)
clear_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Clear all registered values",
)
exit_btn = tk.Button(
    text="Exit Pie Chart Creator",
)


fill="WENS"
append_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=fill)
make_chart_btn.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=fill)
clear_btn.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=fill)
exit_btn.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=fill)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's just a snippet of the code, not the whole code, I thought the whole code would be too long to post here (it's 150 lines) so I posted a snippet here. Thanks for the help though, I'll try it out!

Comment: Look at my example. I tried following Minimal Reproducible example from https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok thanks for the example, I got it now! But I think I should use sticky=WE to expand it in two directions instead of four, so that it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the width and height option in the button’s constructor:

```
button = tk.Button(root, text, width=your_size, height=your_size, command)
```